# Splitting an Pyspark RDD into Different columns and convert to Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd:

```
a,1,2,3,4
b,4,6
c,8,9,10,11
```

I want to convert this into Spark Data Frame with index:

```
df:

Index  Name  Number
 0      a     1,2,3,4
 1      b     4,6
 2      c     8,9,10,11
```

I tried splitting the RDD:

```
parts = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(","))
```

But that resulted in :

```
a,
1,
2,
3,...
```

How do I split and convert the RDD to Dataframe in pyspark such that, the first element is taken as first column, and the rest elements combined to a single column ?

As mentioned in the solution:

```
rd = rd1.map(lambda x: x.split("," , 1) ).zipWithIndex()
rd.take(3)
```

Output:

```
[(['a', '1,2,3,4'], 0),
(['b', '4,6'], 1),
(['c', '8,9,10,11'], 2)]
```

Next Step:

```
rd2=rd2=rd.map(lambda x,y: (y, x[0] , x[1]) ).toDF(["index", "name" ,"number"])
rd2.collect()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 An error occurred while calling 
z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 55.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 
in stage 55.0 (TID 85, localhost, executor driver): 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent 
call last):
```

Is it an issue with the version?

Comment: what spark version are you using?

Comment: Please include the full stack trace. This could be because of data in some rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following RDD transformations and you'll be good to go.

```py
df = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split("," , 1) )      # Split only at first occurence of ,
        .zipWithIndex()                        # Add an incrementing index to each element
        .map(lambda (x,y) : (y, x[0] , x[1]) ) # flatten the structure
        .toDF(["index", "name" , "number"])    # Convert to dataframe

df.show()

#+-----+----+---------+
#|index|name|   number|
#+-----+----+---------+
#|    0|   a|  1,2,3,4|
#|    1|   b|      4,6|
#|    2|   c|8,9,10,11|
#+-----+----+---------+
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for the help.

I tried the way you mentioned. I am still not successful. I have updated my question about what I did. Please look into it.